# How do I extend my Django Default UserCreationForm?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

here is my "forms.py"

```
class CreateUser(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

and here is my "views.py"

```
def register(request):
    form = CreateUser()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            # messages.sucess(request, 'Acccount created!')

            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

and here is my basic register.html so far.

```
<h3>Register</h3>

<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

    <input type="submit" name="Create User">

    <a href="/login">I already have a user!</a>

    {{form.errors}}


</form>
```

The thing is, I need to add a lot of stuff to the registration. The default user/password login is ideal, but the registration needs to have other fields for things like address and credit card number. How do I properly extend this registration, in a way that the login is still the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way or similar, so I'm not sure about using Usercreationform, but I did it in my projects like this. I created a User model in my models.py, and then I just defined the fields I needed for the registerform before the meta class in the forms.py

```py
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```